# Send form data to the same page not functionning

Tags: php

I'm a newbie in PHP, and I would like to send datas from a form and display it into the same page, here is my code for better understanding:

```
<form method="post" action="same_page.php">
<input type="text" name="owner" />
<input type="submit" value="Validate" />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_GET['owner']))
{
   echo "data sent !";
}

?>
```

So normally, after having entered some random text in the form and click "**validate**", the message "**data sent!**" Should be displayed on the page. I guess I missed something, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Your form has method POST and you're checking a GET Value

Comment: You can avoid a lot of complicated programming just by separating things. The problem with your code is that you have method="post" and check for $_GET and not $_POST

Comment: Leave action attribute empty, and check print_r($_POST);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add submit name in your form.You are using POST as method so code should be

```
 <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="owner" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit_value" value="Validate" />
    </form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit_value']))
{
   echo '<pre>';
 print_r($_POST);
}

?>
```

Will display your post values

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
$_GET['owner']
```

With:

```
$_POST['owner']
```

Since you are using the `post` method in your form, you have to check against the `$_POST` array in your PHP code.

Comment: Yea, but no explanation? This might throw an error as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `POST` method in your form.

```
<form method="post" action="same_page.php">
```

So, change your code to:

```
if (count($_POST) && isset($_POST['owner']))
```

Technically, the above code does the following:

1. First checks if there are content in `POST`.
2. Then, it checks if the `owner` is set.
3. If both the conditions are satisfied, it displays the message.

You can actually get rid of `action="same_page.php"` as if you omit it, you will post to the same page.

**Note:** This is a worst method of programming, which you need to change.

Answer (score 0):

You should Replace $_GET['owner'] with $_POST['owner'] as in your form you have specified method='post'